# Como usar AutoMapper 6.2.2 no Asp MVC5?

Tags: mvc, asp, domínio, automapper, viewmodel

Olá, como usar AutoMapper 6.2.2 no Asp MVC5 para mapear as minhas view models para a model de domínio.

Exemplo: no MVC eu uso UsuarioViewModel e no domínio Usuario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vou demostra um exemplo usando a classe categoria e a viewcategoriamodel...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;
using LojaVirtual.Aplicacao.Interfaces;
using LojaVirtual.Aplicacao.ViewModels;
using LojaVirtual.Aplicacao.AutoMapper;
using LojaVirtual.Dominio.Interfaces.Services;
using LojaVirtual.Dominio.Entidades;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace LojaVirtual.Aplicacao.Services
{
    public class AppServiceCategorias : IAppServiceCategorias
    {
        private readonly IServiceCategorias _repositorio;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public AppServiceCategorias(IServiceCategorias repositorio)
        {
            _repositorio = repositorio;
            _mapper = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper;
        }

        public IEnumerable<CategoriasViewModel> GetAll()
        {
            return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoriasViewModel>>(_repositorio.GetAll());
        }

        public CategoriasViewModel GetById(int id)
        {
            return _mapper.Map<CategoriasViewModel>(_repositorio.GetById(id));
        }

        public void Register(CategoriasViewModel customerViewModel)
        {
            var categoria = _mapper.Map<Categorias>(customerViewModel);
            _repositorio.Add(categoria);
        }

        public void Update(CategoriasViewModel customerViewModel)
        {
            var categoria = _mapper.Map<Categorias>(customerViewModel);
            _repositorio.Update(categoria);
        }

        public void Remove(CategoriasViewModel customerViewModel)
        {
            var categoria = _mapper.Map<Categorias>(customerViewModel);
            _repositorio.Remove(categoria);
        }

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            _repositorio.Remove(id);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Esse é um padrão de DDD com uso de MVVM. no geral você tem que fazer o map de ida e de volta para o modelo..

```
return _mapper.Map<CategoriasViewModel>(_repositorio.GetById(id));
```

Veja na lina acima, aqui estou fazendo um mapeamento de um retorno do meu modelo para a minha view model.

Já aqui;

```
var categoria = _mapper.Map<Categorias>(customerViewModel);
                _repositorio.Remove(categoria);
```

Estou fazendo o mapeamento da minha view model para o modelo.

O seu autmap precisa sabe quais objetos serão mapeado quando sua aplicação for iniciada.

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace LojaVirtual.Aplicacao.AutoMapper
{
    public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static IMapper Mapper { get; private set; }
        public static void RegisterMappings()
        {
            var _mapper = new MapperConfiguration((mapper) =>
            {
                mapper.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
                mapper.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
            });

            Mapper = _mapper.CreateMapper();
        }
    }
}
```

A classe acima faz isso. veja que eu tenho dois mapeamentos um de ida e outro de volta entre view model e modelo.

```
using AutoMapper;
using LojaVirtual.Aplicacao.ViewModels;
using LojaVirtual.Dominio.Entidades;

namespace LojaVirtual.Aplicacao.AutoMapper
{
    public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
        {
           CreateMap<Categorias, CategoriasViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

e

```
using AutoMapper;
using LojaVirtual.Aplicacao.ViewModels;
using LojaVirtual.Dominio.Entidades;

namespace LojaVirtual.Aplicacao.AutoMapper
{
    public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<CategoriasViewModel, Categorias>();
        }
    }
}
```

Como falei na inicialização do seu projeto você precisa inicia sua classe de mapeamento.

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            base.OnApplicationStarted();

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
        }
```

Você pode fazer o download do projeto [aqui](https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/LojaVirtual.git).